# how to program the iOS share sheet image in the header section. (See attached image)

Tags: ios

Does anyone have idea how to program the Title Image of the iOS share sheet?

I have an ionic app in which my ios application displays like below (See red circled section)

can anyone shed some light on it?

[image]

A perfect example is by the medium app. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can‘t be done via native code.

The icon is specified in the HTML for the shared webpage (which the device downloads and parses when the share sheet appears).

It’s done via a `link` element in the `header` section. Here’s the relevant HTML from a random Medium page which specifies the black icon:

```
<link data-rh="true" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/fit/c/152/152/1*8I-HPL0bfoIzGied-dzOvA.png"/>
<link data-rh="true" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/fit/c/120/120/1*8I-HPL0bfoIzGied-dzOvA.png"/>
<link data-rh="true" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/fit/c/76/76/1*8I-HPL0bfoIzGied-dzOvA.png"/>
<link data-rh="true" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/fit/c/60/60/1*8I-HPL0bfoIzGied-dzOvA.png"/>
```

You can see the Apple documentation for marking up webpages here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: Awesome. Let me give it a go to see if this indeed gets the icon going.  Also any information you have about the website url that gets displayed under the Title of the Share Card. In the Medium example above it is thebolditalic.com

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't control that. It will always be the domain of the shared URL. You can control the title above it though - which is pulled from the `<title>` element in the header.

Comment: I created a website using github pages with the similar mechanics and Yes you are right we can use this. 
https://khazaddoom.github.io/LearnJS-Everyday/
now i need to figure out how i can get it working in Ionic 4

Comment: If you have a question about ionic specifically, then it would be a good idea to post a new question with appropriate tags. Since my answer was correct, it would be good if you could accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.